# Warp/Deform a highly subdivided plane into an object's surface

Tags: shrinkwrap, surface-deform

Say I have an object which is basically, a Sphere sitting on top of a plane joined together.

I want to deform a highly subdivided plane to wrap around this object's surface basically the plane should acquire the shape of this object.

Here's a drawing in paint to illustrate this. Here black shows the cross section of the original object, and red is the deformed plane that is wrapped around it

[image]

I tried using shrink wrap modifier but this was the best I was able to achieve, I don't think shrink wrap can do something like this, in the picture, right is the original object and left is the subdivided plane after using shrinkwrap modifier.

[image]

Is there something else that I can try? I'm new to blender and I may have missed something. So I would be very grateful if you could help.

Thanks.

Comment: I guess it will work if your second object already has about the same shape

Comment: Can you duplicate your object with SHIFT - D then scale the duplicate up slightly rather than trying to wrap a new plane around it?